# Pass property name of controls to a function

Tags: c#, function, properties, controls

I have function that changes the property of controls based on the control name and the input command.

```
 public void SetControl(string ControlName, string Operation)
    {
        Control Control = this.Controls.Find(ControlName, true)[0];

        switch (Operation)
        {
            case "ok":
                Control.BackColor = Color.Green;
                Control.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                break;
            case "error":
                Control.BackColor = Color.Red;
                Control.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
                break;
        }
    }
```

now I am wondering if there is any way to pass property name as well? of course I can do something like this:

```
if (propertyname=="ForeColor")
 {Control.ForeColor = Color.Black;}
```

but then I should do this for all of the properties that I am going to change! Is there anyway to find and change the property based on its name?

Comment: I can imagine that you'd only change `ForeColor` and `BackColor` unless you also take the new property value as parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  This is precisely what reflection does.

```
var value = Control.GetType().GetProperty(propertyname).GetValue(Control, null);
```

Then set your value

```
Control.GetType().GetProperty(propertyname).SetValue(Control, valueToSet);
```

Comment: @Devid L: Is there any way to pass any value type for the property to the function? I mean like True and False for Enabled property, string for Text property, color for Forecolor property?

Comment: @M0HS3N Yes, though you'd have to define the mapping yourself.  There isn't a "default map", you'd have to create it to determine behavior.  This sounds like it might be an entirely new question however :)